# Fresh Spinnaker Install, Unable to create project/application it's keeps loading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have installed spinnaker on GCP instance Linux Ubuntu 1604. But i am unable to create project or application its keep loading and no response for long time.

Could anyone help me to get this resolved?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try Spinnaker for Google Cloud Platform that you can find in the Marketplace because it "optimized for Google Cloud Platform".

Answer (score 0):

To be very honest i tried several ways to deploy spinnaker in what is called `local debian` install. It never worked for me.

For PoC and deployment to small-medium projects use [Minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker) by Armory. Is a fully functional Spinnaker installation running in `K3S`.

After installing Spinnaker with minnaker (10 mins) configure the Cloud providers taht you wish to use for deploying software to.

thanks